# How to display command output page per page in mongo shell

Tags: windows, mongodb, mongo-shell

`db.serverStatus()` returned many running pages in mongo shell on my Windows 10 machine. What is the command to view the result page by page? `less` , `tail -n` or `man` did not work inside the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think within the mongo shell itself that is not possible but you could call the shell from your command prompt (or PowerShell etc.) and use `more`
Something like this

```
mongo --quiet --eval "db.serverStatus()" | more
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you know these things? I googled for quite a while to no avail.